# How to get the contents of a class or id, with a URL that leads to the page in question

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to retrieve the contents of a (class), and I would like to recover it just with the URL.

I give the URL and it gives me the contentS of a class

http://fr.fetchfile.net/

it's the same principle with this site.

We enter URL of the page and it automatically recovers the URL of the video that seeks for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use URL query parameters to achieve this with an HTTP request. For example, you could use an HTTP GET request and the parameter to search would be apart of the query string.

The site linked does a post request to the server and looks like it's extracting data from Youtube in some form.